# tidying up jQuery method for validating form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a form using jQuery.

It is working perfectly, but I just feel the code is quite "bulky". There is a lot of `if` statements being used to achieve this logic in the `app.sendForm.init()` function. I think this could be tidied and any advice here would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps I should be using a switch statement instead?
Is there another approach I should take to tidy up this code, or do I just have to accept it is going to be quite longwinded?

I have also [posted the question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129354/validate-a-form-using-jquery) where more be a more appropriate forum for this type of question.

```js
"use strict";
var app = app || {};
(function(){

    app.initialize = {
        init: function() {
            app.sendForm.init();
        }
    };

    app.sendForm = {
        init: function(){    
            $("#entry").submit(function( event ) {
                var userEmail = $("#email"),
                    userName = $("#first_name"),
                    userLastName = $("#last_name"),
                    date = $("#birth_day"),
                    month = $("#birth_month"),
                    year = $("#birth_year"),
                    countryName = $("#country");

                    app.validation.dateOfBirth(date, month, year);
                
                if(!app.validation.empty(date) ||!app.validation.empty(month) ||!app.validation.empty(year) || !app.validation.empty(countryName) || !app.validation.email(userEmail) || !app.validation.empty(userName) || !app.validation.empty(userLastName)){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert("didnt send")
                    if(!app.validation.email(userEmail)) {
                        userEmail.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        userEmail.removeClass('invalid');
                    }
                    if(!app.validation.empty(userName)) {
                        userName.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        userName.removeClass('invalid');
                    }
                    if(!app.validation.empty(userLastName)) {
                        userLastName.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        userLastName.removeClass('invalid');
                    }  
                    if(!app.validation.empty(countryName)) {
                        countryName.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        countryName.removeClass('invalid');
                    } 
                    if(!app.validation.empty(date)) {
                        date.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        date.removeClass('invalid');
                    } 
                    if(!app.validation.empty(month)) {
                        month.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        month.removeClass('invalid');
                    } 
                    if(!app.validation.empty(year)) {
                        year.addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        year.removeClass('invalid');
                    } 
                    if(!$('#privacy_terms').is(':checked')) {
                        $('.terms-con').addClass('invalid');
                    } else {
                        $('.terms-con').removeClass('invalid');
                    }

                } else {
                    $("#thank-you").css("display", "block");
                    alert("sent")
                }      
            });
        }
    };
     

    /*
     * Validation
     */
    app.validation = {
        
        email: function(id) {
            // Regex, use this to validate the Email. It return true or false.
            var emailVal = id.val(),
                re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(emailVal);
        },

        empty: function(id) {
            // Use this to validate the Password. Checks if value is empty. It return true or false.
            var elementVal = $.trim(id.val());
            if(elementVal.length > 0)
                return true;
        },

        dateOfBirth: function(date, month, year) {
            var forbiddenAge = 14;
            var DOB = date + " " + month + " " + year;
            var today = new Date();
            var birthDate = new Date(DOB);
            var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
            var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                age--;
            }    
            if(age < forbiddenAge){
                alert("you are under 14");
            }
        }
    };


    app.docOnReady = {
        init: function() {
            app.initialize.init();
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(app.docOnReady.init);

})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}


#entry {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#entry input,
#entry select {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#entry label {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#entry #birth_day,
#entry #birth_month,
#entry #birth_year {
    display: inline-block;
}

#entry input[type=submit] {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#privacy {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.invalid {
    border-color: #ed0000;
    background-color: #ffd8d8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- JQUERY CDN -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <noscript>
        For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript.
        Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
        instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
    </noscript>

    <div>

        <form id="entry">

        <label for="first_name">First name:</label>
        <input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" />

        <label for="last_name">Last name:</label>
        <input id="last_name"  type="text" name="last_name" />

        <label>Country/Region</label>
        <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="">Select Your Country/Region</option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BV">Bouvet island</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
            <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
            <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
        </select>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />

        <label>Date of Birth</label>
        <select id="birth_day" name="birth_day">
            <option value="">DD</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select id="birth_month" name="birth_month">
            <option value="">MM</option>
            <option value="JAN">January</option>
            <option value="FEB">February</option>
            <option value="MAR">March</option>
            <option value="APR">April</option>
            <option value="MAY">May</option>
            <option value="JUN">June</option>
            <option value="JUL">July</option>
            <option value="AUG">August</option>
            <option value="SEP">September</option>
            <option value="OCT">October</option>
            <option value="NOV">November</option>
            <option value="DEC">December</option>
        </select>
        <select id="birth_year" name="birth_year">
            <option value="">YYYY</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
        </select>
        <div id="privacy">
            <input id="privacy_check" type="checkbox" name="privacy_check" />
        
            <label for="privacy_check">I have read and understood the Terms and Conditions.</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="ch_access" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that performs the if/else statements:

```
function setInvalidClass(invalidCondition, jQueryObject) {
    if(invalidCondition) {
        jQueryObject.addClass('invalid');
    }
    else {
        jQueryObject.removeClass('invalid');
    }
}
```

then replace all the if/else statements with a call to the setInvalidClass:

```
setInvalidClass(!app.validation.email(userEmail), userEmail);
setInvalidClass(!app.validation.empty(userName), userName);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give a class to the inputs for the type of validation and then just loop through them:

```js
 $("#entry").submit(function(event) {
   var emptyInputs = $(".empty"), // for empty validation give inputs class of empty
       emailInputs = $(".email"), // for email validation give inputs class of email
       isValid = app.validation.dateOfBirth($("#birth_day"), $("#birth_month"), $("#birth_year"));

   emptyInputs.each(function() {
     var input = $(this);
     if (!app.validation.empty(input)) {
       input.addClass('invalid');
       isValid = false;
     } else {
       input.removeClass('invalid');
     }
   });

   emailInputs.each(function() {
     var input = $(this);
     if (!app.validation.email(input)) {
       input.addClass('invalid');
       isValid = false;
     } else {
       input.removeClass('invalid');
     }
   });

   if (!$('#privacy_terms').is(':checked')) {
     $('.terms-con').addClass('invalid');
     isValid = false;
   } else {
     $('.terms-con').removeClass('invalid');
   }

   if (isValid) {
     $("#thank-you").css("display", "block");
     alert("sent");
   } else {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("didnt send");
   }      
 });
```

or alternatively give all inputs that need validating the same class with a data attribute of what type of validation it is:

```js
$("#entry").submit(function(event) {
  var inputs = $(".validation"),
    isValid = app.validation.dateOfBirth($("#birth_day"), $("#birth_month"), $("#birth_year"));

  inputs.each(function() {
    var input = $(this),
      validationType = input.data('validation-type'),
      inputValid;

    switch (validationType) {
      case 'email':
        inputValid = app.validation.email(input);
        break;
      case 'empty':
        inputValid = app.validation.empty(input);
        break;
    }

    if (!inputValid) {
      input.addClass('invalid');
      isValid = false;
    } else {
      input.removeClass('invalid');
    }
  });


  if (!$('#privacy_terms').is(':checked')) { // this could be added to the loop - just wasn't sure what terms-con element is 
    $('.terms-con').addClass('invalid');
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $('.terms-con').removeClass('invalid');
  }

  if (isValid) {
    $("#thank-you").css("display", "block");
    alert("sent");
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("didnt send");
  }
});
```